# Why do we do a linear regression to find the minimum wavelength in a X-Ray diffraction spectrum?

Tags: solid-state-physics, diffraction, x-ray-crystallography

As part of a an experiment, I was to determine the minimum wavelength emitted by an x-ray source through analysing the detected count rate (detected by a GM counter) of a diffracted x-ray source, via a crystal; NaCl.

From the experimental data, we are able to plot a graph of count rate against x-ray wavelength.

What I do not understand is that the lab manual had asked us to determine the minimum wavelength via linear regression of the points close to the end of the spectrum. The plots and linear regressions are shown below:

[image]

Is there any scientifc reason behind the linear regression? Or is it just a experimental approximation due to the lack of resolution in wavelength?

Why can't we take minimum wavelength to be the point where the count rate meets the background count rate?

Comment: Are you sure that the linear regression was not for determining Planck's constant from these data?

Comment: @Pieter The minimum wavelength found through linear regression was used to determine the plank's constant through the Duane-Hunt relation. But my question is about the need for linear regression to determine minimum wavelength

Answer (score 1):

I believe its due to thermalisation & defects states which may mean that you have a spread of minimum values of X-ray emission.

The density of states should be roughly linear near the band gap (i.e. conduction and valence bands), which means that a linear regression is normally taken until this intersects with the background/zero level.

This is also common practise in photoelectron spectroscopy.